# Rails Webservice--How to pass in search parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, http, solr

I have built a rails app that I wish to adapt to a restful webservice that returns results based upon queries requested from a mobile app. The functionality of the app requires that a search is enabled and I have employed sunspot solr within the rails app. The code for the search (within the respective controller) is as such:

```
    def search(code, dow, period)

    # performing the search as I want it
    @search = Sunspot.search(Camps) do

        fulltext code     

        with(dow).equal_to(true)

        with(period).equal_to(true)

        with(:is_active).equal_to(true)

        order_by :price, :desc
    end
    @search.results
end
```

The major problem is that every rails webservice tutorial only lists very inflexible HTTP requests like: GET  /user/{#}, and to execute you simply input the user #.  But for the app, I will need to pass in varying parameters noting the method head as: search(code, dow, period).

What do I need to change to make the app respond and return the requested information when using a GET and POST requests to some URI 
ie. /search...param...param...etc that can allow for the method head input parameters I have designated?

Comment: this may helps http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll want to look at the `routes` to sort this out

---

**[Non Resourceful Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)**

The problem you have is you're trying to handle variables in the routes, which aren't the typical use case

Rails allows you to send any type of data through the routes - it's just a case of defining them correctly

Here's how we've implemented basic search routing:

```
#config/routes.rb
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'products#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def search                 
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format| --> handles different mime-types (HTML / JSON)
         format.js   { render :partial => "elements/livesearch", :locals => {:search => @products, :query => params[:search]} }
         format.html { render :index }
    end
 end

 #app/models/product.rb --> put your Solr stuff in here
 def self.search(search)
    basic_search(name: search, description: search).take(5)
 end
```